# chain async functions in node.js

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I have an async function, which takes a `my_url` as parameter and update its value each time it runs :

```
function getUser(my_url) {
 var options = {url: my_url};
 request(options, function (body){
    my_url = body.url;
 });
}
```

I want to call this function indefinite times. For example: getUser("a") returns "b", getUser("b") return "c" and so on. What's the best practice here? I've tried making getUser() returns a `promise` with `my_url` as value, but I don't know how to call it repeatedly.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use recursion.  Also sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this (I've changed URL creation a bit to demonstrate the flow with an example URL):

```js
'use strict';

const request = require('request');

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => { setTimeout(resolve, ms); });
}

function promisifiedRequest(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request({ url }, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(body);
    });
  });
}

(async function main() {
  try {
    let url = 'https://example.com';

    while (url !== null) {
      const body = await promisifiedRequest(url);
      url = `https://example.com?q=${
        encodeURIComponent(body.slice(0, Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)))
      }`;
      console.log(url);
      await delay(1000);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function getUser(my_url) {
      var options = {url: my_url};

      if(my_url == "some stop condition") return ;

      request(options, function (body){
         my_url = body.url;
      }).then( response => {
           getUser(response);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here's an example using recursion and `request-promise`:

```
const rp = require('request-promise')

const url = "https://google.com"
var options = {
    uri: url
}

var count = 0

function chain(options, count) {
    const newURL = `${url}/?count=${count}`
    console.log(`Requesting ${newURL}`)
    rp(options).then(function(body) {
        console.log(`Success, body was ${body.length} bytes`)
        count = count + 1;
        if ( count < 20 ) {
            options = {
                uri: newURL
            }
            // recursion

            chain(options, count)
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(`An error occurred: ${err}`)
    })
}

chain(options, count)
```

When I run this here's the output:

```
Requesting https://google.com/?count=0
Success, body was 45855 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=1
Success, body was 45861 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=2
Success, body was 45864 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=3
Success, body was 45875 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=4
Success, body was 45859 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=5
Success, body was 45851 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=6
Success, body was 45882 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=7
Success, body was 45843 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=8
Success, body was 45892 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=9
Requesting https://google.com/?count=9
Success, body was 45835 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=10
Success, body was 45885 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=11
Success, body was 45865 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=12
Success, body was 45851 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=13
Success, body was 45859 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=14
Success, body was 45905 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=15
Success, body was 45848 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=16
Success, body was 45896 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=17
Success, body was 45879 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=18
Success, body was 45877 bytes
Requesting https://google.com/?count=19
Success, body was 45844 bytes
```

You could easily parse out the next URL in the response `then()` if you had a server that behaved that way.  I put in the count to prevent infinite recursion.